# Beginner C: can't move on to next loop

Tags: c

I have a do-while loop:

```
float amount;
do
{
    printf("Input dollar amount owed:\n");
    amount = GetFloat();
}
while (amount <= 0);
```

followed by a while loop and printf:

```
int coins = 0;
while (amount >= 0.25);
{
    amount = amount - 0.25;
    coins++;
}
printf("Number of coins to use: %d\n", coins);
return 0;
```

but when I run and use it, the while loop doesn't run and printf doesn't print.  It looks like this in my terminal, where 1 is the user input:

> Input dollar amount owed: 1

How do I get the program to move onto the while loop and printf?

Comment: Try `while (amount >= 0)`

Comment: GetFloat() grabs the user input as a float

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
while (amount >= 0.25);
                      ^ roh roh
```

I think what you meant was:

```
while (amount >= 0.25)
{
    amount = amount - 0.25;
    coins++;
}
```

`while(x);` is the same as `while(x) { }`

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like a syntax error in `while (amount >= 0.25);` it should be `while (amount >= 0.25)`. just have to remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to get the number of coins for each `amount` entered until a negative number is entered. To do this you want to nest the `while` loops. The pseudo code would be:

```
Get amount
Check if it is greater than 0
Get number of coins and print
Repeat
```

And the actual code could be something like:

```
float amount;
printf("Input dollar amount owed:\n");
amount = GetFloat();
while( amount >= 0 )
{
    int coins = 0;
    while (amount >= 0.25)
    {
        amount -= 0.25;
        coins++;
    }
    printf("Number of coins to use: %d\n", coins);

    printf("Input dollar amount owed:\n");
    amount = GetFloat();
}

return 0;
```

However, your "Get number of coins" is simply doing a division followed by a floor operation. So that doesn't need a loop:

```
int coins = (int) (amount / 0.25f);   // casting to an int will truncate the float.
```